# How do I switch between virtual terminals in a guest system?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-terminal

I want to access virtual consoles in my Ubuntu guests running VirtualBox with Ubuntu guest. However, even if the focus is within the guest window, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> thru <kbd>F6</kbd> I move in a virtual terminal of the **host**, not the guest.

How do I switch to a virtual terminal in the guest OS?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Press <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

<kbd>Host</kbd> inserts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the guest system.

The actual key on your keyboard for <kbd>Host</kbd> is visible in the right bottom of the VM window and can be configured.

1. Open the *VirtualBox Manager*
2. Open *File* -> *Preferences*
3. Open the *Input* tab
4. Click on the field next to *Host key*
5. Press the preferred key for <kbd>Host</kbd>
6. Save the settings by pressing the *OK* button

On my system, I've chosen for <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>. The <kbd>Host</kbd> key is also used for toggling fullscreen (<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

Answer (score 9):

Also for those who are running Virtual Box on Mac OS, remember to press the <kbd>fn</kbd> key in addition to the <kbd>Host</kbd> since it is the key to toggle <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> functionality on Mac OS. So the combination becomes <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>.